# C++ WinInet InternetCloseHandle crash

Tags: c++, wininet

I wrote a program which uses WinInet-library. The program runs for about 8-12 hours a day. At first it connects to the internet, then it uses FTP to down-/up-load files. After that it starts a loop, which starts up to two threads in different time intervals. Both threads are doing `GET`-requests to the same server and are looking like this:

```
private void Thread()
{
    if(!InternetGetConnectedState(NULL, NULL))
    {
        connectToInternet();
    }

    // some code...

    HINTERNET httpOpenRequest = HttpOpenRequest(
        hHTTPConnection,        // InternetConnect-Handle
        L"GET",                 // HTTP-Verb
        request_target,         // FileName
        L"HTTP/1.1",            // HTTP-Version
        NULL,                   // Referer
        NULL,                   // AcceptTypes
        INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD,   // Flags
        0                       // Context
        );

    BOOL httpsRequest = HttpSendRequest(
            httpOpenRequest,    // Handle of HttpOpenRequest
            NULL,               // Headers
            0,                  // Headers-Length
            NULL,               // Optional
            0                   // Optional-Length
            );

    InternetCloseHandle(httpOpenRequest); // App-Crash sometimes here!
}
```

my `connectToInternet`-function is here:

```
int connectToInternet()
{
    DWORD InetTest1 = 16000;
    while (InetTest1 != 0)
    {
        InetTest1 = InternetAttemptConnect(0);
        // wait 1 second for next attempt
        if (InetTest1 != 0)
        {
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    BOOL InetTest2 = FALSE;
    while (!InetTest2)
    {
        InetTest2 = InternetCheckConnection(
            L"http://www.example.com",  // URL
            FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION,  // Flags
            0                           // Reserved
            );
        // wait 1 second for next attempt
        if (!InetTest2)
        {
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    while (hInternetOpen == NULL)
    {
        hInternetOpen = InternetOpen(
            L"Custom-Agent",            // Agent
            INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,  // AccessType
            NULL,                       // ProxyName
            NULL,                       // ProxyBypass
            0                           // Flags
            );

        // wait 1 second for next attempt
        if (hInternetOpen == NULL)
        {
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    while (hHTTPConnection == NULL)
    {
        hHTTPConnection = InternetConnect(
            hInternetOpen,              // InternetOpen-Handle
            L"www.example.com",         // ServerName
            INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, // ServerPort
            NULL,                       // Username
            NULL,                       // Password
            INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,      // Service
            0,                          // Flags
            0                           // Context
            );

        // wait 1 second for next attempt
        if (hHTTPConnection == NULL)
        {
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(the basic workflow for this function I found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383996(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

Now the questions:

***Q1:*** It seems that I rarely get app-crashes when one of the two threads calls `InternetCloseHandle(httpOpenRequest)`. I can't find the reason for these app crashes... Do you have any Ideas?

***Q2:*** The laptop, where the programm is running seems to have internet-connectivity issues because it looses connection for some seconds to some minutes or even hours very often. Therefore I call `connectToInternet()` in both Threads first, if `InternetGetConnectedState(NULL, NULL)` is `false`. Is this step required, or would it also work if I wouldn't make a call to the connect-function? Are the global `HINTERNET`-Handles invalid if the connection breaks?

***[EDIT]*** in the meanwhile I'm suspecting my program for causing the connectivity-problems because I also had no internet-access on my wired-network at home! Is there any mistake I'm making?

Comment: You are misusing `GetLastError()`.  DO NOT call it unless an actual failure is reported first (`InternetOpen()` returns NULL, `InternetConnect()` returns NULL, etc), otherwise you risk seeing error codes from earlier API calls that have nothing to do with the APIs you are calling. Unless explicitly documented, most API functions do not reset `GetLastError()` upon entry, or update `GetLastError()` if successful.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ok, thank you, I will revise my program-code for this misuse!

Comment: @RemyLebeau edited the code now. Any ideas about the error?

Comment: You have multiple threads that are sharing the `hInternetOpen` and `hHTTPConnection` handles, sending HTTP requests in multiple threads over a single HTTP connection without serializing access to the connection. That is a recipe for disaster. So, either serialize access to the connection to avoid race conditions, or else give each thread its own local connection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ok, thank you! How about if I would give each thread its own connection? Would it be a problem if the same thread would be started every 5 seconds? Could my so called "recipe for disaster" be the reason for the connectivity-behavior as shown in question 2?

Comment: @RemyLebeau in the meanwhile I wrote three tiny programs which are using both just the above shown functions. The first program uses shared handles for both threads and the second program uses its own handles in both threads. The third program is like the second, but it does not call `InternetCloseHandle()`. As far as I can say for now, there is no performance-problem with request every 3 seconds. But I do not have any results if the shared handles are causing my errors....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my problem was caused by multiple threads running at the same time and trying to call `InternetCloseHandle()`.

In the meanwhile I rewrote my code. I also tried to involve [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau)'s comments. My code looks like the following examples now:

```
void Thread()
{
    // access-control
    if (ThreadRunning == true)
    {
        return 99;
    }
    ThreadRunning = true;

    // variables
    HINTERNET hInternetOpen = NULL;
    HINTERNET hHTTPConnection = NULL;
    HINTERNET httpOpenRequest = NULL;
    int connectionAttempts;
    string target_string;
    wstring target_wstring;
    LPCWSTR request_target;
    BOOL httpSendRequestSuccessful;
    BOOL httpQueryInfoReceived;
    DWORD statusCode = 0;
    DWORD statusCodeLen = sizeof(statusCode);
    BOOL dataAvailable;
    DWORD numberOfBytesAvailable;
    BOOL internetReadFileSuccessful;
    char buffer[4096] = { "" };
    DWORD numberOfBytesRead;

    // Connect to Internet
    connectionAttempts = 0;
    DWORD InetTest1 = 16000;
    while (InetTest1 != 0)
    {
        InetTest1 = InternetAttemptConnect(0);
        if (InetTest1 != 0)
        {
            connectionAttempts++;
            // prevent an infinite loop
            if (connectionAttempts >= 5)
            {
                // reset access-control
                ThreadRunning = false;

                return 1;
            }
            // wait 1 second if it fails
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    // reset connectionAttempts
    connectionAttempts = 0;
    BOOL InetTest2 = FALSE;
    while (!InetTest2)
    {
        InetTest2 = InternetCheckConnection(
            L"http://www.example.com",  // URL
            FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION,  // Flags
            0                           // Reserved
            );
        if (InetTest2 == FALSE)
        {
            connectionAttempts++;
            // prevent an infinite loop
            if (connectionAttempts >= 5)
            {
                // reset access-control
                ThreadRunning = false;

                return 2;
            }
            // wait 1 second if it fails
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    // reset connectionAttempts
    connectionAttempts = 0;
    while (hInternetOpen == NULL)
    {
        hInternetOpen = InternetOpen(
            L"Custom-Agent",                // Agent
            INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,      // AccessType
            NULL,                           // ProxyName
            NULL,                           // ProxyBypass
            0                               // Flags
            );

        if (hInternetOpen == NULL)
        {
            connectionAttempts++;
            // prevent an infinite loop
            if (connectionAttempts >= 5)
            {
                // reset access-control
                ThreadRunning = false;

                return 3;
            }
            // wait 1 second if it fails
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    // reset connectionAttempts
    connectionAttempts = 0;
    while (hHTTPConnection == NULL)
    {
        hHTTPConnection = InternetConnect(
            hInternetOpen,              // InternetOpen-Handle
            L"www.example.com",         // ServerName
            INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, // ServerPort
            NULL,                       // Username
            NULL,                       // Password
            INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,      // Service
            0,                          // Flags
            0                           // Context
            );
        if (hHTTPConnection == NULL)
        {
            connectionAttempts++;
            // prevent an infinite loop
            if (connectionAttempts >= 5)
            {
                // reset access-control
                onlineSettingsThreadRunning = false;

                // Handle-Cleanup
                InternetCloseHandle(hInternetOpen);

                return 4;
            }
            // wait 1 second if it fails
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    // some code...

    // open HTTP-Request
    httpOpenRequest = HttpOpenRequest(
        hHTTPConnection,        // InternetConnect-Handle
        L"GET",                 // HTTP-Verb (GET or POST)
        request_target,         // FileName
        L"HTTP/1.1",            // HTTP-Version
        NULL,                   // Referer
        NULL,                   // AcceptTypes
        INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD,   // Flags
        0                       // Context
        );
    if (httpOpenRequest == NULL)
    {
        // Handle-Cleanup
        InternetCloseHandle(hHTTPConnection);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternetOpen);

        // reset access-control
        onlineSettingsThreadRunning = false;

        return 5;
    }

    // send HTTP-Request
    httpSendRequestSuccessful = HttpSendRequest(
        httpOpenRequest,    // Handle von HttpOpenRequest
        NULL,               // Headers
        0,                  // Headers-Length
        NULL,               // Optional
        0                   // Optional-Length
        );
    if (httpSendRequestSuccessful == FALSE)
    {
        // Handle-CleanUp
        InternetCloseHandle(httpOpenRequest);
        InternetCloseHandle(hHTTPConnection);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternetOpen);

        // reset access-control
        onlineSettingsThreadRunning = false;

        return 6;
    }

    // read Server-Status
    httpQueryInfoReceived = HttpQueryInfo(
        httpOpenRequest,
        HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
        &statusCode,
        &statusCodeLen,
        NULL
        );
    if (httpQueryInfoReceived == FALSE || statusCode != 200)
    {
        // Handle-CleanUp
        InternetCloseHandle(httpOpenRequest);
        InternetCloseHandle(hHTTPConnection);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternetOpen);

        // reset access-control
        onlineSettingsThreadRunning = false;

        return 7;
    }

    // test, how much bytes are readable
    dataAvailable = InternetQueryDataAvailable(
        httpOpenRequest,
        &numberOfBytesAvailable,
        0,
        0
        );
    if (dataAvailable == FALSE)
    {
        // Handle-CleanUp
        InternetCloseHandle(httpOpenRequest);
        InternetCloseHandle(hHTTPConnection);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternetOpen);

        // reset access-control
        onlineSettingsThreadRunning = false;

        return 8;
    }

    // some code...

    // Close internet-connection
    InternetCloseHandle(httpOpenRequest);
    InternetCloseHandle(hHTTPConnection);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternetOpen);

    // reset access-control
    ThreadRunning = false;

    return 0;
}
```

So my `connectToInternet()`-function does not exist any more. It is now part in each Thread which needs internet-access. It also does not use `GetLastError()` any more as this could deliver wrong results...

I'm still testing my code but it seems to be promising :-)

Comment: "*It also does not use GetLastError() any more as this could deliver wrong results*" - only if you use it incorrectly (which you originally were doing).

Comment: @RemyLebeau of course I meant my usage of the function in my first code, not in general!